# Object reference not set to an instance of an Object in Relation to Non existing Datamember

Tags: c#, xml

The code below is a simplified version and it is difficult create the same source code as the original source code due to many circumstances.

I get a error message that is "Object reference not set to an instance of an Object" when I enter to this code "var dd = playerList.FirstName.ToUpper();" because there is no datamember FirstName in my original source code.

I get random data from the xml file that has element Firstname or not. If I have no element Firstname, the datamember will not be available in the original source code,

My question is,

How should i enable to know if I have a datamember FirstName or not by using C# code?

Thank you!

---

```
<PlayerList>
  <Player>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    <TotalGoalsScored>50</TotalGoalsScored>
    <AverageGoalsPerGame>0.7</AverageGoalsPerGame>
    <Team>
      <Name>Arsenal</Name>
      <YearEstablished>0</YearEstablished>
    </Team>
  </Player>
  <Player>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <FirstName>Jack</FirstName>
    <TotalGoalsScored>0</TotalGoalsScored>
    <AverageGoalsPerGame>0</AverageGoalsPerGame>
  </Player>
</PlayerList>




            string inputXmlPath1 = @"C:\dddd\data.xml";
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(inputXmlPath1))
            {
                XmlSerializer playerListSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PlayerList));

                var playerList = (PlayerList)playerListSerializer.Deserialize(reader);

                var dd = playerList.FirstName.ToUpper();
            }





    [XmlRoot]
    public class PlayerList
    {
        [XmlElement("Player")]
        public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
    }




    public class Player
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int TotalGoalsScored { get; set; }
        public double AverageGoalsPerGame { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I tried the soruce code and I retrieved the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: I can't even compile the code because the `PlayerList` class has no definition for `FirstName`. Are you sure you don't want to just iterate through the list that's returned to you and print each `Player`'s first name?

Comment: In this context I cannot iterate the playerlist in the original source code.

Comment: I can iterate your example just fine. Remove your `var dd` line and replace it with this: `foreach (var player in playerList.Players) { Console.WriteLine(player.FirstName.ToUpper()); }` -- it outputs the 2 player's FirstName's

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get this exception it means that a member you've been trying to call a method (or access a property) on was `null`.

Therefore, you could coalesce the `null` to a default value prior to proceeding:

```
var dd = (playerList.FirstName ?? "").ToUpper(); // dd will be the empty string if FirstName was null
```

For C# 6 you can also use the null-conditional operator:

```
var dd = playerList.FirstName?.ToUpper(); // note: dd will be null is FirstName was null
```

Or check with a normal conditional statement:

```
if (playerList.firstName == null) { // handle the null case
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: The answer is "var dd = (playerList.FirstName ?? "").ToUpper(); // dd will be the empty string if FirstName was null"